# Kubernetes - does not start the role of master

Tags: kubernetes, roles, kubectl

I'm starting a Kubernetes cluster of 3 nodes (1 master, 2 worker)

Trying to go by steps described in Ansible playbook - https://gitlab.com/LinarNadyrov/gcp/tree/master

Applying playbook steps 1,2,3 consequentially

After than, I connect to master to check status:

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION

master NotReady master 17m v1.13.0

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

[enter link description here](https://yadi.sk/i/c_KALwkErwkiVQ)

kubectl get pods -n kube-system

NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

coredns-86c58d9df4-7jc4b                  0/1     Pending   0          3h45m

coredns-86c58d9df4-929xf                  0/1     Pending   0          3h45m

etcd-officemasterkub                      1/1     Running   2          7h26m

kube-apiserver-officemasterkub            1/1     Running   2          7h26m

kube-controller-manager-officemasterkub   1/1     Running   2          7h26m

kube-flannel-ds-5jhbx                     0/1     Pending   0          7h20m

kube-flannel-ds-wqfvs                     0/1     Pending   0          7h20m

kube-proxy-gmngj                          1/1     Running   2          7h27m

kube-proxy-ppbqp                          1/1     Running   1          7h20m

kube-proxy-r2rn6                          1/1     Running   1          7h20m

kube-scheduler-officemasterkub            1/1     Running   2          7h26m

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Status is NotReady

Could anyone help me with it?
What's the problem? What should be done to fix it? Maybe I missed something?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Could you please check `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` ?

Comment: Command execution - https://yadi.sk/i/c_KALwkErwkiVQ

Comment: You flannel pods are in pending state. Those are the k8s CNI pods without those k8s nodes will not able to connect to each other. Hence you node is in not ready state.

Comment: Describe the flannel pod `kubectl describe pod kube-flannel-ds-5jhbx`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

What do you need to do to run CNI?

Comment: You already have CNI pods but they are in pending state. We need to find out why they are in pending status and they should be in running state. Please provide the output of kubectl describe output asked in previous comment

Comment: kubectl describe pod kube-flannel-ds-5jhbx -n kube-system

Comment: Thank. Command execution for kube-flannel-ds-5jhbx -     https://yadi.sk/i/Dek4k2RrFBP7DA
https://yadi.sk/i/dTkpevSAZHidDw
https://yadi.sk/i/wrYab3rdJDaoZg

Comment: Command execution for kube-flannel-ds-wqfvs - https://yadi.sk/i/-0jViCqDUgwRhg
https://yadi.sk/i/hFSheY6nMCmmYA
https://yadi.sk/i/mH_Hzcp0aRHefw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Линар Надыров the problem here is with your flannel yaml file. You did not specify any resources in the DaemonSet so there are no flannel pods spawning.

I did not check any further as it was enough reason why is this issue occurring. You can use this [yaml](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) if this is for testing purposes. Or edit your accordingly to the provided example.

In your [file](https://gitlab.com/LinarNadyrov/gcp/blob/master/3-master.yml) change the line 43 to:

`shell: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml >> pod_network_setup.txt`

You can find more about DaemonSets [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#create-a-daemonset).

Comment: Thanks you.
The cluster started :-)